# Prove using factorials that ${n\choose k}+2{n\choose k+1}+{n\choose k+2}={n+2\choose k+2}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, factorial

Prove using factorials that ${n\choose k}+2{n\choose k+1}+{n\choose k+2}={n+2\choose k+2}$

I think I'm having a bit of algebra problem with this proof. Here is my work thus far:$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}+2\frac{n!}{(k+1)!(n-k-1)!}+\frac{n!}{(k+2)!(n-k-2)!}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{(n+2)!}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}$$$$\frac{(k+1)(k+2)n!}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}+\frac{2(k+2)(n-k)n!}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}+\frac{(n-k-1)(n-k)n!}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{(n+2)!}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}$$$$\frac{n!({k^2}+{3k+2}+{2kn}-2k^2+4n-4k+n^2-kn-n+k^2+k)}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{(n+2)!}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}$$$$\frac{n!(n^2+3n+2)}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{(n+2)!}{(k+2)!(n-k)!}$$But from here I am stuck. How would I algebraically make these two sides match?

Comment: They have the same denominators, so this is literally the same as seeing that $n! (n^2 + 3n + 2) = (n + 2)!$, which is the same as seeing that $n^2 + 3n + 2 = (n + 2)(n + 1)$....

Comment: Ohhh, perhaps I am a bit mathed out for the night if I wasn't able to see that factoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To promote my comment to an answer: You've gotten to the point of comparing two quantities with equal denominator, so it suffices to show that

$$(n^2 + 3n + 2)n! = (n + 2)!$$

But this is equivalent to seeing that

$$n^2 + 3n + 2 = (n + 2)(n + 1)$$

which is clearly true.

Comment: Yes, as soon as you commented I was able to arrive to this step, which helps me finish out with combining $n!(n+2)(n+1)$ into its equivalent $(n+2)!$, which equals the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

Write down the LHS as
$${n \choose k} + {n \choose k+1} + {n \choose k+1} + {n \choose k+2}.$$
Now expand the first two terms to get ${n+1\choose k+1}$. The summation of the second two terms evaluates to ${n+1\choose k+2}$. The addition of the resulted two terms is the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Hint split the middle term as ${n\choose k+1}+{n\choose k+1}$ and then use ${n \choose r}+{n\choose r+1}={n+1\choose r+1}$ by proving it.

Comment: The question says "prove using factorials."

Comment: Is it fine now??

Comment: Well, it doesn't address the vast majority of the algebraic manipulations in the post which are about two lines short of the conclusion. (And I really do wonder if you've yet written an answer that's more than two sentences and doesn't start with the word 'hint.')

Comment: Yes hardly 1-2 answers like that because people here are too  fast in typing which makes giving hints much safe

Comment: Do you think it's better to give full ones

Answer (score 0):

This result, and its generalizations, are made intuitively obvious by the relationship between Pascal's triangle and binomial coefficients; e.g., $$\begin{array}{ccccccc} \ldots & \binom{n}{k} & & \binom{n}{k+1} & & \binom{n}{k+2} & \ldots \\ & \ldots & \binom{n+1}{k+1} & & \binom{n+1}{k+2} & \ldots & \\ & & \ldots & \binom{n+2}{k+2} & \ldots & & \end{array}$$ and recalling that each coefficient is the sum of the two coefficients diagonally above it.